# Can I sue Apple if battery replacement was refused because the program is not available in my country?

Tags: international, consumer-protection

I bought an iPhone 6s in Moldova. I have sometimes unexpected shutdowns. Recently I discovered that Apple has [iPhone 6s Program for Unexpected Shutdown Issues](https://www.apple.com/emea/support/iphone6s-unexpectedshutdown/). I checked the serial number and my iPhone qualifies for a free battery replacement under that program.

On the [Apple Find location site](https://locate.apple.com/md/en/service/?pt=3&lat=47.0167167&lon=28.8497415&address=Chisinau&carrier=no-contract) the official repair service is DAAC SYSTEM INTEGRATOR and there is no alternative.

I called that service and asked if I can bring the device to them but they answered that in Moldova this program is unavailable.

Is Apple legally obligated to make the program available in Moldova?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Apple does not have any legal obligation to make the program available in Moldavia. 
The reason why Apple opened the battery replacement service was to limit the bad press after the BatteryGate had hit the press.

So, to answer your question, you cannot sue on these grounds. 
However, you could theoretically sue Apple on the grounds of planned obsolescence, if such behavior is incriminated in Moldavia. I wouldn't advise on it, however -- it would be extremely expensive and quite a long procedure, for minimal result.

A solution I could have to your problem, would be to get your phone sent & repaired by a store in a country were the program was made available by Apple -- even if you'll have to pay for the shipping costs...

Hope it helps!

Comment: The only situation where Apple has to do something in country B that they do in country A is within the EU, where for example they have to give the same warranty in all EU countries. If you travel you could try to take your phone to a store in a country where they have the program. I don’t know if they are legally required to do the fix, but they might do it anyway (because nobody in the store expects a Moldavian phone).